# How to make simple filtration with django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I faced with a problem. I have a simple drf project with car-entrance permits application.

views.py
`

```
class PermitViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Permit.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = PermitSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['car_number']
```

serializers.py
`

```
class PermitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Permit
        fields = ['car_number', 'is_active']
```

models.py
`

```
class Permit(models.Model):
    car_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

`urls.py`

```
router = SimpleRouter()

router.register(r'permit', PermitViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
]


urlpatterns += router.urls
```

`

i type in my browser
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/permits/?car_number=555`

and i recieve full list of cars
`

```
[{"car_number":"555","is_active":true},{"car_number":"666","is_active":true},{"car_number":"777","is_active":true}]
```

`
It doesn't work, what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please explain your problem and show a stack trace if any exceptions happened.

Answer (score 2):

You specify the fields with the [**`filterset_fields`** attribute <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend), not the <s>`filter_fields`</s> attribute:

```
class PermitViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Permit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PermitSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['car_number']
```

Comment: i've just done that, it didn't help((( and i tried ordering_fields, search_fields - doesn't work also

Comment: @RinoRein: no you use `filter_fields`...

Comment: @RinoRein But that makes no sense as  it is clear that you used `filter_fields` then you should check what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it's might be better to change CharField of 'car_number' in your model to IntegerField

In the case  of API, I recommend the use of third party app like Django-filter
For example,

```
pip install django-filter
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
   .....
   'django-filters'
]
REST_FRAMEWORK={'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'}
```

views.py

```
from django-filters import rest_framework as filters 

class AAA(filters.FliterSet):
  car_number=filtersNumberFilter(field_name='car_number', lookup_expr=555)
  class Meta:
      model=.....
      fields=[...]

class BBB(ModelViewSet):
  ........
  filter_class=AAA
```